Traductor de archivos .po con python
He estado usando la biblioteca googletrans de python para realizar traducciones y a la hora de hacerlo con archivos .po no consigo hacerlo, ya que estoy obteniendo errores para escapar algunos caracteres.
Por ejemplo en esta parte del archivo .po no puedo parsearlo por los caracteres que contiene:
msgctxt "Languages::wk_shopify.shopify_secret_key_help"
msgid "Enter Password here if you are using the private app, And if you are using the custom app then use "custom" in the input"
msgstr "Enter Password here if you are using the private app, And if you are using the custom app then use "custom" in the input"

Esto devuelve el error:
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\polib.py", line 1376, in parse
    raise IOError('Syntax error in po file %s(line %s): '
OSError: Syntax error in po file wk_shopify_connector.po (line 424): unescaped double quote found


A pesar de que sea una pregunta autorrespondida, no olvides mencionar a qué errores estás haciendo referencia.

A la hora de utilizar la libreria googletrans hay que tener en cuenta que necesitas pasar valores que sean stings y que estos no sean escapables por caracteres como /\
Tambien para trabajar con archivos .po debes importar la libreria polib. Y esta tambien es sensible a algunos caracteres por lo que debes tener cuidado con esos para eliminarlos del script en tu caso eliminar "" de la linea donde te da el error lo que quedaria asi:
msgctxt "Languages::wk_shopify.shopify_secret_key_help"
msgid "Enter Password here if you are using the private app, And if you are using the custom app then use custom in the input"
msgstr "Enter Password here if you are using the private app, And if you are using the custom app then use custom in the input"

Un ejemplo basico para traducir el archivo seria algo asi:
import polib
from googletrans import Translator

def translate_po(input_file, output_file, source_lang, target_lang):
    # Cargar el archivo .po
    po = polib.pofile(input_file)

    # Inicializar el traductor de Google
    translator = Translator()

    # Traducir cada entrada del archivo .po
    for entry in po:
        print(entry)
        # Ignorar las entradas con msgctxt
        # Traducir el texto usando Google Translate
        try:
            translation = translator.translate(entry.msgid, src=source_lang, dest=target_lang)
            entry.msgid = translation.text

            print(translation.text)

            translation = translator.translate(entry.msgstr, src=source_lang, dest=target_lang)
            entry.msgctxt = translation.text

            print(translation.text)
        except:
            continue
        
    # Guardar el archivo .po traducido
    po.save(output_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Ruta del archivo .po de entrada
    input_po_file = "wk_shopify_connector.po"
    
    # Ruta del archivo .po de salida
    output_po_file = "output_file.po"
    
    # Idioma origen y destino
    source_language = "en"  # Cambiar al idioma origen del archivo .po
    target_language = "es"  # Cambiar al idioma destino deseado
    
    # Traducir el archivo .po
    translate_po(input_po_file, output_po_file, source_language, target_language)

Con este pequeño script podemos cargar un archivo po el cual vamos a leer haciendo un bucle y leyendo los tipos de entradas y es lo que le vamos a pasar a la libreia de google para que nos lo traduzca, una vez traducido ya podemos volverlo a guardar en otro archivo o cualquier otra operacion
